# Differences in functionalities provided by OpenSSL and Crypto++

Tags: api, interface, openssl, crypto++

I am wondering if there are any functionalities that are explicitly provided in openssl but not in crypto++, or vice versa.

I am trying to write a unified interface to both the libraries so that I can switch between using an underlying crypto library without modifying my calling source code. At this point, I want to figure out if there is anything substantial that can only be done in one of those libraries. I know that the basic hashing, encryption and signing functionalities are provided in both.

Any comments or points of wisdom will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering if there are any functionalities that are explicitly provided in openssl but not in crypto++, or vice versa.

Yes, there are lots of differences between them.

OpenSSL is more similar to Peter Gutmann's [Cryptlib](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/) and GNU's [GnuTLS](http://www.gnutls.org/). Perhaps even Jack Lloyd's [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/). I don't think OpenSSL and Crypto++ is a good comparison.

Crypto++ provides more low level cryptographic primitives. Crypto++ provides nothing related to TLS and DTLS. Crypto++ is like a low level cryptographic Swiss army knife.

OpenSSL provides some low level cryptographic primitives, support for hardware modules, and working TLS and DTLS implementations. Because it supports hardware, it provides a PKCS 11 interface. Because it supports TLS and DTLS, it has richer socket support and an X509 parser.

There are many other similarities and differences. If you want to know a specific similarity or difference, then you need to ask about a specific feature.

---

You might also want to look at the OpenSSL wiki's [Related Links](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Related_Links) page. It lists other, similar libraries.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I actually meant in terms of just low level crypto primitives for encryption, signing, digest etc. I am considering writing a wrapper which will provide basic primitives like RSA signing/encryption, AES, DES, DSA etc, and it can be implemented either in crypto++ or openssl's low level primitives or EVP methods. Hence I was wondering if there are any substantial differences between what these two libraries provide that can pose a problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: For example: The transforms and filters provided in Crypto++ cannot be easily implemented with what openssl provides.

Comment: @SkypeMeSM - OpenSSL uses the *Init/Update/Final* pattern. You can use it too with Crypto++ by way of `Put` and `Get`. Nearly all Crypto++ objects have `Put` and `Get` because they indirectly inherit from a [`BufferedTransformation`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_buffered_transformation.html).